# extra-paths not added to python path with zc.recipe.testrunner

Tags: buildout

I am trying to run tests by adding a version of tornado downloaded from github.com in the sys.path.

```
[tests]
recipe = zc.recipe.testrunner
extra-paths = ${buildout:directory}/parts/tornado/
defaults = ['--auto-color', '--auto-progress', '-v']
```

But when I run bin/tests I get the following error :

```
ImportError: No module named tornado
```

Am I not understanding how to use extra-paths ?

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into generated `bin/tests` script if it contains your path? It will tell definitely if your buildout.cfg is correct or not. Maybe problem is elsewhere. Because it seem that your code is ok.

If you happen to regularly include various branches from git/mercurial or elsewhere to buildout, you might be interested in [mr.developer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer). `mr.developer` can download and add package to `develop =`. You wont need to set `extra-path` in every section.